# Me and my opposite

Tags: riddle, pattern, wordplay, computer-puzzle

I am the most powerful, a group of people.
My opposite was once my rival, able to change between others.

We can both be found in the same surroundings, often doing very different things.
For example, one of us could be relaxed while the other is making things happen.
One could be underneath while the other is making connections.
One could be in court while the other is getting help from equipment.
One can bring power while the other shows disease.
On the radio, one of us could be reading while the other gives chase.
Normally, though, our interests overlap.

**What am I and what  is my opposite?**

**Bonus: where else can we both be found?**

Hint 1:

> The [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) tag is important to this question, [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) not so much.

Hint 2:

> As suggested by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/19783/13152), the answer is a letter or small group of letters rather than a word.

Hint 3:

> Each 1/2 line gives a single word that is a clue towards the final answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You and your opposite are

> the letters **us** and **su**.

I am the most powerful, a group of people.

> The US has the most powerful military force in the world, and "us" describes a group of people.

My opposite was once my rival, able to change between others.

> The Soviet Union, which was the US's rival in the Cold War, could be abbreviated as SU, and "su" is a Unix command to change to another user.

We can both be found in the same surroundings, often doing very different things.
For example, one of us could be relaxed while the other is making things happen.

> One is laid-back and "ca**su**al", while the other is "ca**us**al".

One could be underneath while the other is making connections.

> One is "**su**b", while the other is "**US**B", a standard for connecting devices.

One could be in court while the other is getting help from equipment.

> One might be "**su**ing" in court, while the other is "**us**ing" equipment.

One can bring power while the other shows disease.

> A "P**SU**" provides power, while "p**us**" is usually a symptom of disease.

On the radio, one of us could be reading while the other gives chase.

> While these aren't spelt the same, they sound alike - "per**us**ing" vs "pur**su**ing".

Normally, though, our interests overlap.

> "Us" and "su" are both in "usually", sharing an S.

Bonus: where else can we both be found?

> There are a number of other words with both "us" and "su", such as "suspicious" or "suspire".

Comment: A brilliant solution and a very good answer!

Comment: Yes! This is the right answer! BTW, which clue did you 'get' the answer from or did you combine them?

Comment: It was mostly from the "group of people" and "change between others", especially once I saw it was a small group of letters. The "computer-puzzle" tag helped to confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay), maybe the answer is

> that you and your opposite are both letters of the alphabet, appearing respectively in various words?

*For example, one of us could be relaxed while the other is making things happen.

One could be underneath while the other is making connections.

One could be in court while the other is getting help from equipment.

One can bring power while the other shows disease.
On the radio, one of us could be reading while the other gives chase.*

> The only letter appearing in RELAXED, UNDERNEATH, COURT, POWER, and READING is **R**; the only letter appearing in THINGS HAPPEN (?), CONNECTIONS, EQUIPMENT, DISEASE, and CHASE is **E**.

*I am the most powerful, a group of people.
My opposite was once my rival, able to change between others.*

> E and R both appear in the middle of the word POWERFUL, and E appears several times in CHANGE BETWEEN OTHERS.

*We can both be found in the same surroundings, often doing very different things.

Normally, though, our interests overlap.*

> Many words contain both E and R. For example, ARSEHOLES!

*What am I and what is my opposite?*

> You are R, and your opposite is E.

*Bonus: where else can we both be found?*

> KNICKERS!

Comment: You're the closest person so far! It's not a _single_ letter though. Try looking at the clues a little less specifically. I might add another hint to this effect.

Comment: Also, +1 for 'arseholes' and 'knickers' :)

Comment: @Somo145 Is the answer OW, as in p**ow**erful, cr**ow**d, c**ou**rt, p**ow**er?

Comment: No - those aren't the words you're looking for. Each 1/2 line gives a single word.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be

> an electromagnetic wave. Specifically the electric field and magnetic field making up the wave.

We can both be found in the same surroundings, often doing very different things.

> Electric and magnetic fields coexist in nature, but both are useful in their own applications.

For example, one of us could be relaxed while the other is making things happen.

> In an electromagnet, the electric field gives rise to a magnetic field, and that magnetic field is used to lift heavy objects.

One could be underneath while the other is making connections.

> The magnetic field is present in telephone wires, where electric impulses are used to relay conversations.

One could be in court while the other is getting help from equipment.

*Not sure about this clue...*

One can bring power while the other shows disease.

> Electric fields across power lines transfer power across cities. Meanwhile, MRI machines use magnetic fields to detect diseases and injuries in humans.

On the radio, one of us could be reading while the other gives chase.

> The magnetic field is playing sound through speakers while the electric field is being used to reach out to devices across the city.

Normally, though, our interests overlap.

*Not sure about this clue...*

Comment: Good answer, but no. The correct answer is simpler than this. Also, half of the clues are unexplained :) I like your explanations, though, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

A bit morbid, but I'm thinking you are

> The dying/deceased, with your opposite being the living.

I am the most powerful, a group of people.

> The number of dead people dwarfs the number of living people and "there's power in numbers".

My opposite was once my rival, able to change between others.

> Possibly referencing living people who are in comas or who are cryogenically frozen and be considered dead.

We can both be found in the same surroundings, often doing very different things.

> A living person can do many different things, but a dead person is, well, dead. Both are found on/in the Earth.

For example, one of us could be relaxed while the other is making things happen.

> The dead usually have a relaxed expression on their face. The living are going on about their lives doing things.

One could be underneath while the other is making connections.

> Underneath, referencing people who are buried underneath the soil in a grave. Living people can make connections between other living things.

One could be in court while the other is getting help from equipment.

> A living person could be a lawyer in court, while a dying person could be on life support (hospital equipment).

One can bring power while the other shows disease.

> A living person can provide power/electricity to buildings whereas a dying person maybe be dying from a disease.

On the radio, one of us could be reading while the other gives chase.

*Not too sure about this one.*

Normally, though, our interests overlap.

> The living have interests and the dead had those interests while still alive.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> **the majority**, the "opposite" being the minority

I am the most powerful, a group of people.

> the majority is powerful because they have more votes, and a greater number of people

My opposite was once my rival, able to change between others.

> in the past, minority groups were less accepted than in today's world (although there is still plenty of pressure to conform to the majority)

We can both be found in the same surroundings, often doing very different things.

> self-explanatory

For example, one of us could be relaxed while the other is making things happen.

> Usually, the people who make things happen are in the minority, while the majority of people are more relaxed

One could be underneath while the other is making connections.

> The majority of people are "underneath," or behind-the-scenes, and the minority of people are the spokespeople to the public (making connections).

One could be in court while the other is getting help from equipment.

> Not sure about this one

One can bring power while the other shows disease.

> The majority brings power, while the minority shows disease

On the radio, one of us could be reading while the other gives chase.

> Not sure

Normally, though, our interests overlap.

> The interests of the majority and minority overlap on many issues

Comment: I like your answer! Unfortunately, though, it's not right :) +1 anyway.